# Count a word using loop

Tags: python, loops, count

Im trying to count how many time the word `[error]` is in a file.
This is how my attempt is looking:

```
with open(r'test.log') as logfile:
   for line in logfile:
        error = line.count('[error]')
        print(error)
```

The outcome of this result a list like this:

0

1

1

0

1

etc.
I want the outcome to be "Error 10" or how many times the word occur

Comment: Why not add counts for each line together?

Comment: @ForceBru How do you mean? Im pretty new to Python so i dont really understand.

Comment: You could look up how to sum multiple numbers in a loop. Here you have many counts (`error`), but the goal (as far as I understand) is to produce the _total_ number of occurrences, so you should sum all `error`s together in the loop. This is usually done with the `+=` operator.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to get the total number of occurrences insted of a list with false or true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = 0
with open('test.log', 'r') as logfile:
    lines = logfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        count += line.count('[error]')
print(count)
```

Comment: Here is the code you need to do it

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening is the loop is printing how many errors are in each line every time it loops. What you might want to do is have an external variable outside the loop that the loop adds to to find the total sum.

```
error_count = 0
with open(r'test.log') as logfile:
   for line in logfile:
        error_count += line.count('[error]')
   print("error" + str(error_count))
```